# How do I implement an IF statement into a while loop, and keep while loop running indefinitely? (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, while-loop

Take the following while loop I made which outputs the amount of times "string" appears in the file (file path and string ommited) every 60 seconds.

```
while true; do /path/to/file | grep -i "string" | wc -l; sleep 60; done
```

What's the best/easiest way to implement an IF statement so that, if the output gets above 100 I can send an email. I need the while loop to continue running indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that you can pipe directly to another command that contains an `if` statement.

```
while true; do
  /path/to/file | grep -i "string" | wc -l | {
    read count
    if [[ $count -gt 100 ]]; then
      send_email
    fi
    echo "$count"
  }
done
```